# push data to local variable from promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
// Get user Miners Json
function getUserMinersJson(username) {
  console.log(`getUserMinersJson ${username}`);
  data = [];
  miners
    .filter((miner) => miner.username === username)
    .forEach(function (entry) {
      if (entry.username != undefined) {
        data.push(entry.data);
      }
    });
  const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    minerModel.getUserMiners(username, data, function (err, dbminers) {
      if (err) {
        reject("miner model error get database miners");
      } else {
        return resolve(dbminers);
      }
    });
  });
  promise.then((dbminers) => {
    if (dbminers.length > 0) {
      dbminers.forEach(function (entry) {
        const index = data.findIndex((miner) => miner.mac === entry.mac);
        if (index === -1) {
          console.log(`mac is : ${entry.mac}`);
          console.log(`push data offline user ${entry.mac} `);
          entry.username = username;
          data.push(entry);
        }
      });
    } // end of if length
  });
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

i am trying to push offline user to global variable called "data" from promise but it didnt save

just return the data with empty but when i use console.log inside promise it work

some output

```
send to agent triggered asd
{ action: 'connected', data: [] }
mac is : dododo
push data offline user dododo
mac is : asdasdasd2
push data offline user asdasdasd2
mac is : asdasdasd
push data offline user asdasdasd
[]
```

Comment: You can't (early enough). Just return the promise from your function!

Comment: please explain how ?

Comment: You need to know how JavaScript engine executes your script. the issue here is very clear, you use the `data` variable by console logging it or returning it without waiting for the asynchronous function to be finished.